# Process "expect" HTTP header in Express app

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm building an Express application that does some low-level HTTP processing. Among the requests to be processed are requests with arbitrary [`Expect` headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect) ("arbitrary" meaning, "containing values other than the only specified value `100-continue`").

I have naively assumed that I would able to access and process the `Expect` header in my request handler function just as I would any other HTTP request header:

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();

app.post("/foo", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.header("accept"));
    console.log(req.header("expect"));

    // do stuff

    res.status(200).json({foo: "bar"});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This works just fine as long as no `Expect` header is actually set. However, as soon as the app receives a request with such a header set, it does not even seem to call the request handler, but reject the request outright with a `417 Expectation Failed` status:

```
$ http -v localhost:3000/foo foo=bar Expect:202-accepted
POST /foo HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*
[...]
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.9
Expect: 202-accepted

{
    "foo": "bar"
}

HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Mon, 16 Mar 2020 13:12:28 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

On a first glance, it seems that Express gives some special treatment to requests with an `Expect` header and rejects them before they even reach the request handler. How can I "convince" Express to do otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requests with an `Expect` header are not caught by Express, but by Node.JS' [standard `http` module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) (which is used by Express under the hood). The `http.Server` class even has a specific `checkExpectation` event handler that is called for requests with an `Expect` header that is not equal to `100-continue` (emphasis mine):

> #### Event: 'checkExpectation'
>
> Added in: v5.5.0
>
> - request <http.IncomingMessage>
> - response <http.ServerResponse>
>
> Emitted each
>   time a request with an HTTP Expect header is received, where the value
>   is not 100-continue. **If this event is not listened for, the server
>   will automatically respond with a 417 Expectation Failed as
>   appropriate.**
>
> When this event is emitted and handled, the 'request' event will not
>   be emitted.

Since no `request` event is emitted, there requests are never handled by Express. And when no listener is configured for the `checkExpectation` event, the `http.Server` will simply reject the request with `417 Expectation Failed`.

A possible solution is to not just call `app.listen`, but to define your own HTTP server (with your Express app as request listener), and then listen to `checkExpectation` events and manually pass these into your express app:

```
import express from "express";
import * as http from "http";

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.post("/foo", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.header("accept"));
    console.log(req.header("expect"));

    // do stuff

    res.status(200).json({foo: "bar"});
});

server.on("checkExpectation", app);
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Isn't the goal of the expect headers that it's a "pre-flight" and if the server returns a 100 response, then the client will send the real http request afterwards?  So, it doesn't seem you'd want to respond to the checkExpectation event with your normal route handling, but rather a specific handler that looks at the headers to see if the request looks OK.  The usual example is to examine `content-length` to see if it's too big or not.

Comment: Also, `app.listen()` returns the normal http server object so you can still use `app.listen()` if you want and then use that returned server object to set up the `checkExpectation` listener.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the feedback! Yes, that's the usual (and only) standard-compliant use-case for `expect`. However, there are some non-standard scenarios that I've seen occasionally in which this might be of use. For example, in some API designs (take [RHEV](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Virtualization/3.1/html/Developer_Guide/sect-REST_API_Guide-Common_Features-Resources-Deleting_Resources.html), for example), a `Expect: 202-accepted` header might be used as an indicator to process requests asynchronously if they would otherwise not be.

Comment: Yea, I guess it depends upon the OP's usage of the Expect header which they do not disclose.

Comment: I'm also the OP, just btw . I just self-answered because this cost me an hour of work, I didn't find anything on this and wanted to share my learnings. I wanted to keep the question as generic as possible, which is why I didn't go too much into detail on my specific fringe use case.

Comment: Well my point was that how you use that `checkExpectation` event depends upon what you are doing with the expect headers.